# Losing audio in re-encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, mp4, h.264

I have some DVDs I want to save MP4s from. The video files are VOB files. I can play them if I change the extension to .mp4, but I can't use the seek bar in Windows Media Player. Also, the files are very large. I'm using ffmpeg to re-encode them with h.264 and compress. The video is coming out fine, but I'm losing the audio. The command I'm using is:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i <input file> -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 24 -c:a copy -y <output file>
```

I can only seem to capture the tail end of the output, but here it is:

```
frame= 6504 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   31114kB time=00:03:36.86 bitrate=1175.3kbits/
frame= 6543 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   31289kB time=00:03:38.20 bitrate=1174.7kbits/
frame= 6582 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   31447kB time=00:03:39.55 bitrate=1173.4kbits/
frame= 6617 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   31616kB time=00:03:40.73 bitrate=1173.3kbits/
frame= 6656 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   31849kB time=00:03:41.95 bitrate=1175.5kbits/
frame= 6690 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   32024kB time=00:03:43.10 bitrate=1175.9kbits/
frame= 6724 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   32194kB time=00:03:44.22 bitrate=1176.2kbits/
frame= 6761 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   32367kB time=00:03:45.47 bitrate=1176.0kbits/
frame= 6797 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   32551kB time=00:03:46.62 bitrate=1176.6kbits/
frame= 6832 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   32745kB time=00:03:47.80 bitrate=1177.5kbits/
frame= 6868 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   32936kB time=00:03:49.02 bitrate=1178.1kbits/
frame= 6909 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   33157kB time=00:03:50.40 bitrate=1178.9kbits/
frame= 6951 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   33353kB time=00:03:51.80 bitrate=1178.7kbits/
frame= 6990 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   33545kB time=00:03:53.08 bitrate=1179.0kbits/
frame= 7028 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   33739kB time=00:03:54.36 bitrate=1179.3kbits/
frame= 7068 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   33944kB time=00:03:55.71 bitrate=1179.7kbits/
frame= 7108 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   34125kB time=00:03:56.99 bitrate=1179.6kbits/
frame= 7149 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   34348kB time=00:03:58.43 bitrate=1180.1kbits/
frame= 7188 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   34538kB time=00:03:59.74 bitrate=1180.1kbits/
frame= 7222 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   34729kB time=00:04:00.86 bitrate=1181.2kbits/
frame= 7257 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   34955kB time=00:04:01.98 bitrate=1183.3kbits/
frame= 7289 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   35163kB time=00:04:03.10 bitrate=1184.9kbits/
frame= 7325 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   35389kB time=00:04:04.28 bitrate=1186.7kbits/
frame= 7364 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   35580kB time=00:04:05.60 bitrate=1186.8kbits/
frame= 7403 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   35812kB time=00:04:06.88 bitrate=1188.3kbits/
frame= 7441 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   35997kB time=00:04:08.12 bitrate=1188.5kbits/
frame= 7485 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   36188kB time=00:04:09.63 bitrate=1187.5kbits/
frame= 7526 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   36401kB time=00:04:10.97 bitrate=1188.1kbits/
frame= 7566 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   36574kB time=00:04:12.32 bitrate=1187.5kbits/
frame= 7606 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   36746kB time=00:04:13.66 bitrate=1186.7kbits/
frame= 7644 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   36926kB time=00:04:14.88 bitrate=1186.8kbits/
frame= 7677 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   37113kB time=00:04:16.00 bitrate=1187.6kbits/
frame= 7711 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   37317kB time=00:04:17.21 bitrate=1188.5kbits/
frame= 7747 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   37574kB time=00:04:18.36 bitrate=1191.3kbits/
frame= 7782 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   37780kB time=00:04:19.52 bitrate=1192.6kbits/
frame= 7814 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   37985kB time=00:04:20.64 bitrate=1193.9kbits/
frame= 7848 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   38207kB time=00:04:21.76 bitrate=1195.7kbits/
frame= 7885 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   38423kB time=00:04:22.91 bitrate=1197.2kbits/
frame= 7924 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   38615kB time=00:04:24.32 bitrate=1196.8kbits/
frame= 7961 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   38821kB time=00:04:25.50 bitrate=1197.8kbits/
frame= 7998 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   39067kB time=00:04:26.72 bitrate=1199.9kbits/
frame= 8034 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   39290kB time=00:04:27.90 bitrate=1201.4kbits/
frame= 8073 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   39480kB time=00:04:29.24 bitrate=1201.2kbits/
frame= 8109 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   39665kB time=00:04:30.40 bitrate=1201.7kbits/
frame= 8152 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   39885kB time=00:04:31.84 bitrate=1201.9kbits/
frame= 8195 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   40070kB time=00:04:33.31 bitrate=1201.0kbits/
frame= 8235 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   40271kB time=00:04:34.62 bitrate=1201.3kbits/
frame= 8275 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   40464kB time=00:04:35.96 bitrate=1201.2kbits/
frame= 8316 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   40657kB time=00:04:37.31 bitrate=1201.0kbits/
frame= 8357 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   40844kB time=00:04:38.68 bitrate=1200.6kbits/
frame= 8395 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   41050kB time=00:04:39.96 bitrate=1201.1kbits/
frame= 8435 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   41211kB time=00:04:41.31 bitrate=1200.1kbits/
frame= 8476 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   41359kB time=00:04:42.72 bitrate=1198.4kbits/
frame= 8520 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   41520kB time=00:04:44.16 bitrate=1197.0kbits/
frame= 8560 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   41663kB time=00:04:45.47 bitrate=1195.6kbits/
frame= 8606 fps= 76 q=27.0 size=   41829kB time=00:04:46.97 bitrate=1194.0kbits/
frame= 8646 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   42010kB time=00:04:48.38 bitrate=1193.3kbits/
frame= 8688 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   42183kB time=00:04:49.72 bitrate=1192.7kbits/
frame= 8727 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   42428kB time=00:04:51.07 bitrate=1194.1kbits/
frame= 8766 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   42598kB time=00:04:52.38 bitrate=1193.5kbits/
frame= 8803 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   42758kB time=00:04:53.60 bitrate=1193.0kbits/
frame= 8845 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   42949kB time=00:04:55.00 bitrate=1192.6kbits/
frame= 8886 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   43110kB time=00:04:56.38 bitrate=1191.6kbits/
frame= 8925 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   43346kB time=00:04:57.69 bitrate=1192.8kbits/
frame= 8966 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   43528kB time=00:04:59.04 bitrate=1192.4kbits/
frame= 9009 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   43725kB time=00:05:00.48 bitrate=1192.1kbits/
frame= 9051 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   43925kB time=00:05:01.85 bitrate=1192.1kbits/
frame= 9091 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   44112kB time=00:05:03.23 bitrate=1191.7kbits/
frame= 9132 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   44309kB time=00:05:04.54 bitrate=1191.9kbits/
frame= 9172 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   44544kB time=00:05:05.92 bitrate=1192.8kbits/
frame= 9214 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   44740kB time=00:05:07.29 bitrate=1192.7kbits/
frame= 9256 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   44919kB time=00:05:08.73 bitrate=1191.9kbits/
frame= 9293 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   45155kB time=00:05:09.92 bitrate=1193.6kbits/
frame= 9330 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   45342kB time=00:05:11.20 bitrate=1193.6kbits/
frame= 9370 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   45553kB time=00:05:12.51 bitrate=1194.1kbits/
frame= 9408 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   45750kB time=00:05:13.76 bitrate=1194.5kbits/
frame= 9447 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   45949kB time=00:05:15.07 bitrate=1194.7kbits/
frame= 9484 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   46136kB time=00:05:16.35 bitrate=1194.7kbits/
frame= 9523 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   46350kB time=00:05:17.56 bitrate=1195.6kbits/
frame= 9558 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   46523kB time=00:05:18.81 bitrate=1195.4kbits/
frame= 9596 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   46726kB time=00:05:20.03 bitrate=1196.1kbits/
frame= 9633 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   46911kB time=00:05:21.34 bitrate=1195.9kbits/
frame= 9671 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   47106kB time=00:05:22.56 bitrate=1196.3kbits/
frame= 9710 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   47289kB time=00:05:23.87 bitrate=1196.1kbits/
frame= 9748 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   47470kB time=00:05:25.12 bitrate=1196.1kbits/
frame= 9788 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   47654kB time=00:05:26.46 bitrate=1195.8kbits/
frame= 9825 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   47845kB time=00:05:27.74 bitrate=1195.9kbits/
frame= 9860 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   48071kB time=00:05:28.86 bitrate=1197.5kbits/
frame= 9895 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   48255kB time=00:05:30.01 bitrate=1197.8kbits/
frame= 9932 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   48456kB time=00:05:31.29 bitrate=1198.2kbits/
frame= 9975 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   48643kB time=00:05:32.70 bitrate=1197.7kbits/
frame=10013 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   48825kB time=00:05:33.95 bitrate=1197.7kbits/
frame=10050 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   49009kB time=00:05:35.26 bitrate=1197.5kbits/
frame=10088 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   49191kB time=00:05:36.41 bitrate=1197.8kbits/
frame=10130 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   49348kB time=00:05:37.88 bitrate=1196.4kbits/
frame=10173 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   49501kB time=00:05:39.32 bitrate=1195.1kbits/
frame=10217 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   49656kB time=00:05:40.80 bitrate=1193.6kbits/
frame=10259 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   49825kB time=00:05:42.17 bitrate=1192.9kbits/
frame=10299 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   50008kB time=00:05:43.52 bitrate=1192.6kbits/
frame=10340 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   50209kB time=00:05:44.92 bitrate=1192.5kbits/
frame=10380 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   50377kB time=00:05:46.24 bitrate=1191.9kbits/
frame=10416 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   50576kB time=00:05:47.39 bitrate=1192.7kbits/
frame=10453 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   50768kB time=00:05:48.64 bitrate=1192.9kbits/
frame=10493 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   50959kB time=00:05:49.98 bitrate=1192.8kbits/
frame=10530 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   51135kB time=00:05:51.26 bitrate=1192.5kbits/
frame=10568 fps= 76 q=27.0 size=   51307kB time=00:05:52.48 bitrate=1192.4kbits/
frame=10607 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   51515kB time=00:05:53.76 bitrate=1192.9kbits/
frame=10647 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   51696kB time=00:05:55.10 bitrate=1192.6kbits/
frame=10680 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   51866kB time=00:05:56.25 bitrate=1192.6kbits/
frame=10714 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   52064kB time=00:05:57.37 bitrate=1193.4kbits/
frame=10749 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   52276kB time=00:05:58.49 bitrate=1194.6kbits/
frame=10784 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   52486kB time=00:05:59.71 bitrate=1195.3kbits/
frame=10822 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   52677kB time=00:06:00.92 bitrate=1195.6kbits/
frame=10859 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   52878kB time=00:06:02.24 bitrate=1195.8kbits/
frame=10894 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   53069kB time=00:06:03.32 bitrate=1196.5kbits/
frame=10930 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   53266kB time=00:06:04.54 bitrate=1197.0kbits/
frame=10969 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   53462kB time=00:06:05.92 bitrate=1196.9kbits/
frame=11007 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   53676kB time=00:06:07.13 bitrate=1197.7kbits/
frame=11047 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   53854kB time=00:06:08.41 bitrate=1197.5kbits/
frame=11086 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   54028kB time=00:06:09.79 bitrate=1196.9kbits/
frame=11124 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   54202kB time=00:06:11.04 bitrate=1196.7kbits/
frame=11165 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   54380kB time=00:06:12.41 bitrate=1196.2kbits/
frame=11201 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   54542kB time=00:06:13.60 bitrate=1195.9kbits/
frame=11241 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   54751kB time=00:06:14.94 bitrate=1196.2kbits/
frame=11279 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   54929kB time=00:06:16.25 bitrate=1195.9kbits/
frame=11314 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   55106kB time=00:06:17.37 bitrate=1196.2kbits/
frame=11353 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   55313kB time=00:06:18.62 bitrate=1196.8kbits/
frame=11389 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   55504kB time=00:06:19.84 bitrate=1197.0kbits/
frame=11426 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   55696kB time=00:06:21.12 bitrate=1197.2kbits/
frame=11464 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   55895kB time=00:06:22.40 bitrate=1197.4kbits/
frame=11500 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   56110kB time=00:06:23.58 bitrate=1198.3kbits/
frame=11537 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   56280kB time=00:06:24.80 bitrate=1198.2kbits/
frame=11572 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   56464kB time=00:06:25.98 bitrate=1198.4kbits/
frame=11610 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   56663kB time=00:06:27.26 bitrate=1198.6kbits/
frame=11647 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   56863kB time=00:06:28.44 bitrate=1199.2kbits/
frame=11683 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   57060kB time=00:06:29.66 bitrate=1199.6kbits/
frame=11724 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   57230kB time=00:06:31.07 bitrate=1198.8kbits/
frame=11761 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   57415kB time=00:06:32.28 bitrate=1199.0kbits/
frame=11798 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   57592kB time=00:06:33.53 bitrate=1198.9kbits/
frame=11834 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   57797kB time=00:06:34.75 bitrate=1199.4kbits/
frame=11872 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   58030kB time=00:06:36.00 bitrate=1200.5kbits/
frame=11912 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   58214kB time=00:06:37.34 bitrate=1200.2kbits/
frame=11952 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   58381kB time=00:06:38.62 bitrate=1199.8kbits/
frame=11993 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   58552kB time=00:06:40.03 bitrate=1199.0kbits/
frame=12035 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   58725kB time=00:06:41.47 bitrate=1198.3kbits/
frame=12077 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   58911kB time=00:06:42.88 bitrate=1197.9kbits/
frame=12116 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   59117kB time=00:06:44.12 bitrate=1198.3kbits/
frame=12154 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   59303kB time=00:06:45.40 bitrate=1198.3kbits/
frame=12190 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   59492kB time=00:06:46.59 bitrate=1198.6kbits/
frame=12222 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   59716kB time=00:06:47.68 bitrate=1199.9kbits/
frame=12259 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   59912kB time=00:06:48.96 bitrate=1200.1kbits/
frame=12299 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   60099kB time=00:06:50.24 bitrate=1200.1kbits/
frame=12336 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   60309kB time=00:06:51.48 bitrate=1200.6kbits/
frame=12374 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   60553kB time=00:06:52.73 bitrate=1201.8kbits/
frame=12412 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   60744kB time=00:06:53.98 bitrate=1202.0kbits/
frame=12445 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   60910kB time=00:06:55.07 bitrate=1202.1kbits/
frame=12479 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   61102kB time=00:06:56.22 bitrate=1202.6kbits/
frame=12515 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   61285kB time=00:06:57.47 bitrate=1202.6kbits/
frame=12555 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   61436kB time=00:06:58.78 bitrate=1201.8kbits/
frame=12595 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   61588kB time=00:07:00.12 bitrate=1200.9kbits/
frame=12634 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   61782kB time=00:07:01.47 bitrate=1200.8kbits/
frame=12670 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   61967kB time=00:07:02.62 bitrate=1201.1kbits/
frame=12709 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   62147kB time=00:07:03.96 bitrate=1200.8kbits/
frame=12751 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   62335kB time=00:07:05.37 bitrate=1200.5kbits/
frame=12793 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   62515kB time=00:07:06.68 bitrate=1200.2kbits/
frame=12835 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   62695kB time=00:07:08.12 bitrate=1199.6kbits/
frame=12873 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   62920kB time=00:07:09.37 bitrate=1200.4kbits/
frame=12910 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   63082kB time=00:07:10.62 bitrate=1200.0kbits/
frame=12951 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   63280kB time=00:07:11.96 bitrate=1200.1kbits/
frame=12989 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   63464kB time=00:07:13.24 bitrate=1200.0kbits/
frame=13028 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   63637kB time=00:07:14.56 bitrate=1199.6kbits/
frame=13068 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   63811kB time=00:07:15.93 bitrate=1199.1kbits/
frame=13109 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   64019kB time=00:07:17.21 bitrate=1199.5kbits/
frame=13146 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   64190kB time=00:07:18.52 bitrate=1199.1kbits/
frame=13186 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   64369kB time=00:07:19.84 bitrate=1198.9kbits/
frame=13223 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   64533kB time=00:07:21.08 bitrate=1198.5kbits/
frame=13263 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   64701kB time=00:07:22.43 bitrate=1198.0kbits/
frame=13300 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   64892kB time=00:07:23.64 bitrate=1198.2kbits/
frame=13339 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   65068kB time=00:07:24.96 bitrate=1198.0kbits/
frame=13378 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   65257kB time=00:07:26.20 bitrate=1198.1kbits/
frame=13418 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   65405kB time=00:07:27.58 bitrate=1197.1kbits/
frame=13457 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   65547kB time=00:07:28.89 bitrate=1196.2kbits/
frame=13500 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   65690kB time=00:07:30.33 bitrate=1195.0kbits/
frame=13545 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   65855kB time=00:07:31.80 bitrate=1194.1kbits/
frame=13589 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   66003kB time=00:07:33.28 bitrate=1192.9kbits/
frame=13632 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   66168kB time=00:07:34.68 bitrate=1192.1kbits/
frame=13674 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   66317kB time=00:07:36.09 bitrate=1191.1kbits/
frame=13717 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   66461kB time=00:07:37.56 bitrate=1189.9kbits/
frame=13752 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   66580kB time=00:07:38.72 bitrate=1189.0kbits/
frame=13788 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   66723kB time=00:07:39.96 bitrate=1188.3kbits/
frame=13823 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   66878kB time=00:07:41.08 bitrate=1188.2kbits/
frame=13861 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   67064kB time=00:07:42.36 bitrate=1188.2kbits/
frame=13895 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   67235kB time=00:07:43.45 bitrate=1188.4kbits/
frame=13935 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   67392kB time=00:07:44.83 bitrate=1187.7kbits/
frame=13975 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   67541kB time=00:07:46.14 bitrate=1187.0kbits/
frame=14014 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   67685kB time=00:07:47.48 bitrate=1186.1kbits/
frame=14055 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   67831kB time=00:07:48.86 bitrate=1185.1kbits/
frame=14098 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   67976kB time=00:07:50.27 bitrate=1184.1kbits/
frame=14129 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   68144kB time=00:07:51.29 bitrate=1184.5kbits/
frame=14165 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   68328kB time=00:07:52.51 bitrate=1184.6kbits/
frame=14200 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   68518kB time=00:07:53.66 bitrate=1185.0kbits/
frame=14234 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   68708kB time=00:07:54.81 bitrate=1185.4kbits/
frame=14273 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   68881kB time=00:07:56.06 bitrate=1185.3kbits/
frame=14310 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   69057kB time=00:07:57.37 bitrate=1185.0kbits/
frame=14342 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   69246kB time=00:07:58.46 bitrate=1185.6kbits/
frame=14370 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   69455kB time=00:07:59.39 bitrate=1186.9kbits/
frame=14398 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   69663kB time=00:08:00.28 bitrate=1188.2kbits/
frame=14432 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   69869kB time=00:08:01.44 bitrate=1188.9kbits/
frame=14468 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   70070kB time=00:08:02.59 bitrate=1189.4kbits/
frame=14503 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   70253kB time=00:08:03.77 bitrate=1189.6kbits/
frame=14539 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   70456kB time=00:08:04.96 bitrate=1190.2kbits/
frame=14576 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   70648kB time=00:08:06.20 bitrate=1190.3kbits/
frame=14612 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   70874kB time=00:08:07.45 bitrate=1191.1kbits/
frame=14643 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   71048kB time=00:08:08.48 bitrate=1191.5kbits/
frame=14676 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   71237kB time=00:08:09.56 bitrate=1192.0kbits/
frame=14710 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   71436kB time=00:08:10.68 bitrate=1192.6kbits/
frame=14743 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   71623kB time=00:08:11.80 bitrate=1193.0kbits/
frame=14777 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   71796kB time=00:08:12.96 bitrate=1193.1kbits/
frame=14810 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   72035kB time=00:08:14.04 bitrate=1194.4kbits/
frame=14841 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   72239kB time=00:08:15.07 bitrate=1195.4kbits/
frame=14869 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   72409kB time=00:08:16.00 bitrate=1195.9kbits/
frame=14899 fps= 76 q=30.0 size=   72585kB time=00:08:17.02 bitrate=1196.3kbits/
frame=14932 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   72789kB time=00:08:18.11 bitrate=1197.1kbits/
frame=14964 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   72983kB time=00:08:19.16 bitrate=1197.7kbits/
frame=14997 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   73176kB time=00:08:20.28 bitrate=1198.2kbits/
frame=15029 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   73363kB time=00:08:21.34 bitrate=1198.8kbits/
frame=15060 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   73615kB time=00:08:22.40 bitrate=1200.3kbits/
frame=15094 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   73824kB time=00:08:23.48 bitrate=1201.2kbits/
frame=15125 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   74011kB time=00:08:24.54 bitrate=1201.7kbits/
frame=15158 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   74196kB time=00:08:25.63 bitrate=1202.1kbits/
frame=15189 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   74373kB time=00:08:26.68 bitrate=1202.4kbits/
frame=15222 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   74564kB time=00:08:27.77 bitrate=1203.0kbits/
frame=15254 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   74744kB time=00:08:28.89 bitrate=1203.2kbits/
frame=15285 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   74912kB time=00:08:29.92 bitrate=1203.5kbits/
frame=15319 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   75141kB time=00:08:31.04 bitrate=1204.5kbits/
frame=15352 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   75337kB time=00:08:32.09 bitrate=1205.2kbits/
frame=15384 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   75558kB time=00:08:33.18 bitrate=1206.1kbits/
frame=15412 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   75731kB time=00:08:34.11 bitrate=1206.7kbits/
frame=15444 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   75912kB time=00:08:35.20 bitrate=1207.1kbits/
frame=15475 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   76099kB time=00:08:36.22 bitrate=1207.6kbits/
frame=15504 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   76294kB time=00:08:37.21 bitrate=1208.4kbits/
frame=15534 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   76488kB time=00:08:38.17 bitrate=1209.2kbits/
frame=15564 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   76711kB time=00:08:39.20 bitrate=1210.4kbits/
frame=15597 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   76910kB time=00:08:40.28 bitrate=1211.0kbits/
frame=15627 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   77101kB time=00:08:41.24 bitrate=1211.7kbits/
frame=15661 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   77296kB time=00:08:42.43 bitrate=1212.0kbits/
frame=15697 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   77488kB time=00:08:43.61 bitrate=1212.3kbits/
frame=15732 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   77681kB time=00:08:44.76 bitrate=1212.7kbits/
frame=15767 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   77862kB time=00:08:45.98 bitrate=1212.7kbits/
frame=15801 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   78069kB time=00:08:47.10 bitrate=1213.3kbits/
frame=15833 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   78244kB time=00:08:48.16 bitrate=1213.6kbits/
frame=15867 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   78441kB time=00:08:49.28 bitrate=1214.1kbits/
frame=15897 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   78609kB time=00:08:50.30 bitrate=1214.3kbits/
frame=15930 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   78808kB time=00:08:51.42 bitrate=1214.8kbits/
frame=15963 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   79018kB time=00:08:52.51 bitrate=1215.6kbits/
frame=15996 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   79228kB time=00:08:53.56 bitrate=1216.4kbits/
frame=16027 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   79434kB time=00:08:54.62 bitrate=1217.2kbits/
frame=16059 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   79624kB time=00:08:55.68 bitrate=1217.7kbits/
frame=16103 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   79806kB time=00:08:57.15 bitrate=1217.1kbits/
frame=16148 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   79984kB time=00:08:58.68 bitrate=1216.3kbits/
frame=16189 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   80149kB time=00:09:00.00 bitrate=1215.9kbits/
frame=16230 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   80308kB time=00:09:01.40 bitrate=1215.1kbits/
frame=16273 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   80500kB time=00:09:02.81 bitrate=1214.9kbits/
frame=16311 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   80679kB time=00:09:04.16 bitrate=1214.6kbits/
frame=16346 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   80861kB time=00:09:05.31 bitrate=1214.7kbits/
frame=16376 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   81043kB time=00:09:06.24 bitrate=1215.4kbits/
frame=16407 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   81229kB time=00:09:07.32 bitrate=1215.8kbits/
frame=16439 fps= 75 q=30.0 size=   81413kB time=00:09:08.38 bitrate=1216.2kbits/
frame=16469 fps= 74 q=30.0 size=   81588kB time=00:09:09.37 bitrate=1216.6kbits/
frame=16503 fps= 74 q=30.0 size=   81787kB time=00:09:10.17 bitrate=1217.8kbits/
frame=16515 fps= 74 q=-1.0 Lsize=   82483kB time=00:09:10.98 bitrate=1226.4kbits
/s
video:56333kB audio:25809kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB mu
xing overhead: 0.414423%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] frame I:74    Avg QP:23.62  size: 31695
[libx264 @ 044828a0] frame P:4215  Avg QP:26.02  size:  8043
[libx264 @ 044828a0] frame B:12226 Avg QP:28.60  size:  1753
[libx264 @ 044828a0] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  0.4%  5.7% 93.4%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] mb I  I16..4: 17.7% 65.8% 16.4%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  1.3%  0.2%  P16..4: 47.6% 13.8% 10.1%
 0.0%  0.0%    skip:26.4%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 39.1%  2.6%  0.6%
 direct: 1.3%  skip:56.3%  L0:49.5% L1:46.9% BI: 3.5%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] 8x8 transform intra:61.7% inter:77.0%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] direct mvs  spatial:100.0% temporal:0.0%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 68.2% 68.4% 23.7% inter: 12.8% 17.
0% 1.0%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 24% 42%  6% 28%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12%  8%  9%  9% 14% 11% 13%
 9% 14%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 23%  6%  7% 10%  8% 12%
 9% 15%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 32% 33% 18% 17%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:1.2% UV:0.2%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] ref P L0: 37.6% 12.0% 27.8%  8.4% 13.5%  0.8%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] ref B L0: 54.4% 29.2% 12.4%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] ref B L1: 88.2% 11.8%
[libx264 @ 044828a0] kb/s:837.45

H:\HHVL\Scripts>
```

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your command (without `-loglevel`).

Comment: I'm trying...The output is too long to copy. I tried: `ffmpeg -i "HAMMER Training Water Hammer  Prop Room 16.mp4" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 24 -c:a copy -y test.mp4 > output.txt`, But nothing is showing up in the file.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard any suggestions? I tried `dir > output.txt` and it performed as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the complete console output. You can trim the repeating `frame=` lines.

Comment: I just can't copy them. The command window only stores so much. It's unfortunate that redirecting to a file is not working.

Comment: 1) add a '-t 5' after -i <filename>. The console output should be small enough for complete capture. 2) if that's too big, run ffprobe -i <filename> 3) your audio bitrate is roughly 384 kbps. Seems like AC-3 6 ch. I'm not too sure, but I don't think ISO MP4 container takes AC-3. You may have to encode audio to AAC.

Comment: And to redirect to a file suffix "2> logfile.txt" to your command like this "ffmpeg -i ..... -y <output> 2> logfile.txt".

Comment: IDK why exactly ffmpeg in a Windows cmd window doesn't update its status line in place like it's supposed to, instead of scrolling up the screen.  To work around it, use `FFREPORT=file=ffreport.txt ffmpeg ...` to run ffmpeg with the FFREPORT environment variable set (so it can log before even parsing its command line).  Or if that doesn't work in `cmd.exe`, then `ffmpeg -report ...`.

Comment: If the input is VOBs, you might do better with treating them as an actual DVD, and using one title.  This can avoid timestamp jumps and other stuff you can get when a single video spans multiple VOBs.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm beginning to think that is the best approach. I should just rip the DVDs to MP4s. I can probably find some free utility to do that.

Comment: I forget if ffmpeg can parse dvds directly.  If not, `transcode` has a handy tool called `tccat` to dump the stream from a dvd to an MPEG transport-stream.  See http://gentoovps.net/dvd-to-h264/ for example.

Comment: Apparently, ffmpeg *can* do it, but only by amalgamating the VOBs. [Here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6585/dvd-ripping-with-ffmpeg) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1564791)